# MySQL sort result similar to .NET recordset

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I need to migrate a code from .NET to MySQL and looking for an analog to the recordset SORT function. In my .NET code it was easy to create a recordset and run multiple sort operation across different fields. It was extremely fast even for large recordsets of over half a million records.

I understand that in MySQL I can use an ORDER BY clause, but in that case I will need to run multiple db queries, which is not a good solution from the performance point.

How can I sort a query result on different fields without executing multiple queries? PHP array sort functions or there are some better options?

Thanks!

Comment: "I understand that in MySQL I can use an ORDER BY clause, but in that case I will need to run multiple db queries, which is not a good solution from the performance point.", are you sure about this? :p

Comment: Yes. The max number of columns to be sorted is about 50-60, i.e. I will need to run 50-60 queries, each about 0.5 sec. 30 sec execution time is to bad.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` works on multiple fields. Is that what you mean?

```
SELECT [column list] FROM table
ORDER BY field1, field2
```

Comment: No, I need separate sorted columns - on a single field, not on multiple fields.

Comment: I'm not sure we can provide you much more help then, without understanding how your data is structured

Comment: The query returns 50-60 columns. Then I need to do some math with each of these columns sorted by value. In .NET I could sort fields of the returned recordset one-by-one, which was much faster than runnung multiple queries or sort arrays. Since, there is no similar functionality in MySQL that could sort query results, the only solution I see is to dump the result to a 2-dimensional array and them use PHP array sort functions.